# Passing a configuration object to a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I often use the below design pattern to create jQuery plugins.  I specify default values in the plugin, and allow the user to change them when they initialize the plugin.  Normally, my `default` object just contains string properties, not objects, but this time, I wish to make one of the default properties an object (`default_obj_1` in my example). At the bottom of the script, you see me attempt to change one of the properties of by passing the plugin `{default_value_2: 666, default_obj_1.default_prop_3: 434}`, but it invalid JavaScript and errors out.  I also tried passing it `{default_value_2: 666, default_obj_1: {default_prop_3: 434}` but it appears to overwrite the other values which should remain.

How do I update just one of the default values in the jQuery plugin?

```
(function($){
    var defaults = {
        default_value_1 : 123,
        default_value_2 : 321,
        default_value_3 : 111,
        default_obj_1   : {
            default_prop_1  : 444,
            default_prop_2  : 534,
            default_prop_3  : 231
        }
    };

    var methods = {
        init : function (options) {
            var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            return this.each(function () {
                //Do something using settings
            });
        }
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(method) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.myPlugin' );
        }    
    };

    }(jQuery));

$(function(){

    var myPlugin=$('#elem').myPlugin({default_value_2:666,default_obj_1.default_prop_3:434});

    var myPlugin=$('#elem').myPlugin({default_value_2:666,default_obj_1:{default_prop_3:434} });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
```

to

```
var settings = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options); // notice the first param TRUE
```

to do a deep (recursive) merge.

Comment: Ah ha!  Thanks Mathlentics.  I need to run, but will test it when I get back and select this as an answer (provided it works :)